# Having error in Struts - Hibernate project deployment

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, struts

I am having error when deploying web application build on Struts and hibernate.

the stacktrace I get is:

```
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing
> JSP page /index.jsp at line 23   20: <body> 21:  22: <h1>Contact
> Manager</h1> 23: <s:actionerror xmlns:s="#unknown" /> 24:  25: <s:form
> action="add" method="post" xmlns:s="#unknown"> 26:    <s:textfield
> name="contact.firstName" label="Firstname" />  
> 
> Stacktrace:
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:524)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:435)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)  
> 
> root cause    The Struts dispatcher cannot be found.  This is usually
> caused by using Struts tags without the associated filter. Struts tags
> are only usable when the request has passed through its servlet
> filter, which initializes the Struts dispatcher needed for this tag. -
> [unknown location]
>   org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.TagUtils.getStack(TagUtils.java:60)
>   org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.StrutsBodyTagSupport.getStack(StrutsBodyTagSupport.java:44)
>   org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doStartTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:48)
>   org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005factionerror_005f0(index_jsp.java:185)
>   org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:94)
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:393)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)  
> 
> note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache
> Tomcat/6.0.13 logs.  
> 
> My web.xml file is :--
> 
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <web-app version="2.5" 
>   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
>   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
>   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
>   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">  
> <welcome-file-list>
>     <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>   </welcome-file-list>   <filter>      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>      <filter-class>
>           org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher      </filter-class>   </filter>   <filter-mapping>      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>  
>   <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>   </filter-mapping></web-app>
```

How could I give code page because it gives error when updating the same post.

Comment: show your jsp file code.

Comment: how could i give the jsp page. because i am unable to update this post with the jsp code